# graphiql UI is broken for Serverless/AWS-Lambda setup

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, serverless-framework, apollo-server, serverless-framework-offline

Here's a reference setup of AWS Lambda and Serverless and GraphQL that i'm following:

https://github.com/serverless/serverless-graphql-apollo

I'm trying with `yarn run start-server-lambda:offline` to start the project offline, it does start without any problems, but upon navigating to `/graphiql`, I get this:

[image]

Comment: Can you include your `serverless.yml` and possibly the part of your handler where you set `graphql` endpoint that `graphiql` uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a configuration problem somewhere.

Basically, it's sending a request to `/production/graphql` when it should have been sending it to `/graphql`.

Comment: it seems you were right about the misconfiguration. But it didn't solve everything. Now all requests to `/graphiql` return the UI html: https://github.com/Birowsky/serverless-graphql-apollo/commit/3e788a0ce2fa81c69cc8a4f05862c4547194645b

Comment: I commented on that repo.